# Direct sum of standard Hilbert A-modules

Tags: operator-algebras, hilbert-modules

For any $C^\ast$-algebra $A$, don't we have the isomorphism $\mathcal{H}_A \oplus \mathcal{H}_A \cong \mathcal{H}_A$? In some places, it is only mentioned when $A$ is $\sigma$-unital. But $\mathcal{H}_A \cong A \otimes l^2$, and since tensor product commutes with direct sums, we should be getting $(A \otimes l^2) \oplus (A \otimes l^2) \cong A \otimes (l^2 \oplus l^2) \cong A \otimes l^2$. What's wrong here?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempts to prove this isomorphism.

Comment: @AnneBauval done

Comment: How do you define $\mathcal{H}_A$?

Answer (score 2):

There is no mistake. The result holds for general $C^*$-algebras, as you proved.

Comment: Are you considering the fact that $\mathcal{H}_A$ need not be countable generated?

Comment: @Anupam But look at your own proof: you never use assumption?

Comment: Yes, but still Hilbert modules seem a bit scary as compared to Hilbert Spaces, so was just confirming! :)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong and your proof shows that the hypothesis $A$ is $\sigma$-unital is useless (you could complete your algebraic proof whith a little argument justifying why the isomorphism goes over to the completions).

You will find a related theorem, the "Stabilization or Absorption Theorem", in Bruce Blackadar's *K-Theory for Operator Algebras*: (for *any* $C^*$-algebra $B$),

"The theorem in this form is due to Kasparov [...]

> Theorem 13.6.2. If $E$ is a countably generated Hilbert $B$-module, then $E\oplus H_B\cong H_B.$"

and

> "Exercise 13.7.1 (a) Use the stabilization theorem to prove that if $B$ is $\sigma$-unital and $E$ is a countably generated full Hilbert $B$-module, then $E^\infty\cong H_B.$" ($E^\infty:=E\otimes l^2$, and "full" means $\langle E,E\rangle=B$.)

Enlightning comment below by @MaoWao: "I think the stabilization theorem is the reason why some authors state this result [$\mathcal{H}_A \oplus \mathcal{H}_A \cong \mathcal{H}_A$] only for $σ$-unital $C^∗$-algebras, because only then it is a direct consequence."

Comment: The point is $\mathcal{H}_A$ is not countable generated if $A$ is not $\sigma$-unital

Comment: I know, still it is not countably generated. In fact, $\mathcal{H}_A$ is countably generated iff $A$ is $\sigma$-unital

Comment: Well $A$ itself need not be generated by countably many elements if it doesn't have a countable approximate unit.

Comment: Sorry if I am being foolish, but can you give a countable generating set (according to your definition of course) which exhibits $\mathcal{H}_A$ as a countably generated $A$-module?

Comment: @AnneBauval But $A$ does not need to have a unit (if it does, then $A$ is of course $\sigma$-unital).

Comment: Actually, I think the stabilization theorem (which is due to Kasparov, not Blackadar, if I'm not mistaken) is the reason why some authors state this result only for $\sigma$-unital $C^\ast$-algebras, because only then it is a direct consequence. So I think it's not bad for context.